# How to set lease time and server identifier fields in DHCPOFFER packet?

Tags: packet, dhcp

When I see the DHCP RFC at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt , it says that lease time and server identifier fields come under options. Which bits in the DHCP packet actually represent these field?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to give you a specific byte offset to look at - you have to interpet the "Options" section of the packet. The Options can be given in any order.

Take a look at the definitions of the Options here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#DHCP_options

> Options are variable length octet strings. The first octet is the
>   option code, the second octet is the number of following octets and
>   the remaining octets are code dependent.

So if you have DHCPOFFER packet to decode, you need to start at the beginning of the Options section (octet offset 812 into the entire DHCPOFFER packet), and interpret each Option (code, length, data) until you reach the end of the packet. Then look at which Option had a code of 51 (lease time) followed by a length octet of value 4 and then 4 octets of data, or 54 (Server identifier) again followed by length 4 and 4 octets of data.